# how to pass different values on selecting different radio button in text box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm working on different radio button how can I pass the different values on selecting radio button, like if user select domestic then the value that pass to all text box will be `2` n if user select a in radio button then value pass to be `3` and so on for different radio button selection.This value passing mean if user enter any value in text box name `text1` that value which user enter and the value of the radio button that user select multiply and then display in text box below. if user select different radio button then that raddio button value and the value enter in text box got multiply.

My code:

```
    <style>
div {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
div label {
    width: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
input[readonly] {
    background: #eee;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loads').closest('div').hide();

    $('input[name="myradio"]').change(function(){
        if($('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val() == '100')
            $('#loads').closest('div').hide();
        else
            $('#loads').closest('div').show();
    });

    $('#btn-calculate').click(function(){
        var units = parseInt( $('#units').val() );
        var radioVal = $('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val();
        $('input[readonly]').each(function(){
            var val = units * radioVal * ($(this).data('value') ? $(this).data('value') : 100);
            $(this).val(val);
        });
    });
});

</script>



  <form method="POST" name="form1">
<label>Select your category:</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="100" name="myradio" checked="checked" />Domestic</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="200" name="myradio" />a</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="300" name="myradio" />b</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="400" name="myradio" />c</label>
    <div>
        <label for="units">No of units(kwh) used</label>
        <input type="text" name="units" id="units" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="loads">Connected loads(kwh)</label>
        <input type="text" name="loads" id="loads" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="actual">Actual</label>
        <input type="text" data-value="2.60" readonly="readonly" name="actual" id="actual" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="tax">Tax</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="tax" id="tax" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="elec">Elec</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="elec" id="elec" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="charges">Charges</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="charges" id="charges" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="amount" id="amount" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="govt">Govt</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="govt" id="govt" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="result">Result</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="result" id="result" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="btn-calculate">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

one problem is that i display one text box name `mytext`  display on if user  select `a` ,`b` ,`c` from the radio button and hide on selecting `domestic` radio button but whenever i refresh my page its always selected on a and the text box appear how can i remove this . i created the js -fiddle here is the link `http://jsfiddle.net/MUGzE/` kindly answer my both question i will really appreciate.

Comment: So do you want to calculate your Actual=2.60*NoOfUnits*RadioButtonValue ??? and so on..

Comment: then what will be the values for radio button b and c? domestic and a have 100 and 200 respectively..

Comment: @AyyappanSekar help me in this

Comment: @AyyappanSekar i have ask question on your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to share this with you. I made a cleaner version of your markup and used jQuery to make JS calls more compact, also I used data-attributes to set the value that needs to be multiplied for each input.

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loads').closest('div').hide();

    $('input[name="myradio"]').change(function(){
        if($('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val() == '100')
            $('#loads').closest('div').hide();
        else
            $('#loads').closest('div').show();
    });

    $('#btn-calculate').click(function(){
        var units = parseInt( $('#units').val() );
        var radioVal = $('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val();
        $('input[readonly]').each(function(){
            var val = units * radioVal * ($(this).data('value') ? $(this).data('value') : 100);
            $(this).val(val);
        });
    });
});
```

**[Full demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/c9sHt/1/)**

Comment: which jquery is to be ?

Comment: jquery is jquery 1.9.1 ?

Comment: you need to wrap the code in a document.ready function, check the update above

Comment: i edited my code n  paste your answer which i paste kindly see this n let me know the issuse

Comment: You need two `script` tags, one to load jquery, the other where the code is

Comment: sir if i want to add the value of two text box i.e. amount = actual + charges and similarly wants to subtarct the two text box values i.e. govt=actual - units n similarly result= amount- govt how can i do thi kindly help me in this

Comment: If each input is going to have a different formula then I suggest you remove the loop that goes through all readonly inputs and set the value for each one manually. Example: `$('#amount').val(parseInt($('#actual').val()) + parseInt($('#charges').val()));` But that is outside the scope of your original question. Please accept my answer if you feel that it resolved the issue you posted originally.

Comment: plz help me in this there are different actual values on selection of different radio button

Comment: can u plz tell me about this

Comment: So the 2.6 changes when a different radio button is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use

```
<input type="radio" name="myCheckbox" value="Hello World"
    onClick="document.getElementById('myTextId').value = this.value;">
</input>
<input type="radio" name="myCheckbox" value="Goodbye World"
    onClick="document.getElementById('myTextId').value = this.value;">
</input>

<input type="text" id="myTextId" name="myText" value=""></input>
```

EDIT: Or without inline JS

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var radios = document.getElementsByClassName('myRadioClass');
        for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            radios[i].onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById('myTextId').value = this.value;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="radio" name="myCheckbox" class="myRadioClass" value="Hello World"></input>
<input type="text" id="myTextId" name="myText" value=""></input>
```

Another EDIT: Hopefully this is what you want. The onClick event now both transfers the text from the radio button value, and shows a secondary div.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var radios = document.getElementsByClassName('myRadioClass');
        for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            radios[i].onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById('myTextId').value = this.value;
                document.getElementById('hiddenBox').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="radio" name="myCheckbox" class="myRadioClass" value="Hello World"></input>
<input type="text" id="myTextId" name="myText" value=""></input>

<div id="hiddenBox" style="display:none;">Poof!</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by display it?

Comment: mean on clcking radio button a b or c text box that name mytext will appear n on selecting domestic text box disappear

Comment: Do you mean that the Text Input should be hidden until a radio button is selected?

Comment: not input the complete box it appears only when user select a , b or c radio button

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't tell what it is you want. Probably this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know am late to post this answer. Did some changes to your code so that it works.

1. removed checked attribute of your radio buttons as we need to get a
   radio button value which is checked
2. changed your toggle method to get the checked radio buttons value
3. multiplied the radio button value to put the text boxes value

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MUGzE/1/).

you can get the radio button value by passing it to the toggle() and your toggle() will be

```
function toggle(checkbox)
{
    //you can get the redio button value here itself
    checkboxValue = checkbox.value;
    var name = checkbox.nextSibling.data;
if(name != 'domestic')
 document.getElementById('mytext').style.visibility='visible';
else
 document.getElementById('mytext').style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

then you can calculate your outputs by

```
 document.getElementById("value_output").value = 2.60 * input_value *checkboxValue;
```

Comment: there is different actual value on the selection of radio button how can i do this.

Comment: actual values mean the the text box label as actual

Comment: i couldnt get your question :(