# How to get different values of text box in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery and I need to pass different values of same text box on different radio button clicks like text box name `actual` has four different values on selecting the different radio buttons how can I pass this?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#loads').closest('div').hide();
$('#units').val('0');
$('input[name="myradio"]').change(function(){
    if($('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val() == '100')
        $('#loads').closest('div').hide();
    else
        $('#loads').closest('div').show();
});
$('input[readonly]').each(function(){
            $(this).val('0'); 
});

$('#actual').val('2.56');
 $("input:radio[name=myradio], #btn-calculate").click(function() {
     if ($('input[name=myradio]:radio:checked').val() == '100'){
       $('#actual').val('2.56');
       $('#charges').val('20');
     } else if ($('input[name=myradio]:radio:checked').val() == '200'){
       $('#actual').val('3.50');
       $('#charges').val('40');
     } else if ($('input[name=myradio]:radio:checked').val() == '300'){
       $('#actual').val('4.50');
       $('#charges').val('60');
     } else if ($('input[name=myradio]:radio:checked').val() == '400'){
       $('#actual').val('5.50');
       $('#charges').val('80');
     }
    $('#tax').val(($('#units').val())*($('#actual').val()));
    $('#elec').val(($('#units').val())*($('#actual').val()));
     $('#amount').val(parseInt(($('#charges').val()))+parseInt(($('#actual').val())));
      $('#govt').val(($('#actual').val())-($('#units').val()));
         $('#result').val(($('#amount').val())-($('#govt').val()));
});

</script>

    <form method="POST" name="form1">
    <label>Select your category:</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="100" name="myradio" checked="checked" />Domestic</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="200" name="myradio" />a</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="300" name="myradio" />b</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="400" name="myradio" />c</label>
    <div>
        <label for="units">No of units(kwh) used</label>
        <input type="text" name="units" id="units" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="loads">Connected loads(kwh)</label>
        <input type="text" name="loads" id="loads" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="actual">Actual</label>
        <input type="text" data-value="2.60" readonly="readonly" name="actual" id="actual" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="tax">Tax</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="tax" id="tax" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="elec">Elec</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="elec" id="elec" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="charges">Charges</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="charges" id="charges" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="amount" id="amount" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="govt">Govt</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="govt" id="govt" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="result">Result</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="result" id="result" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="btn-calculate">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Similarly I want this in text box name `amount=charges+actual` and in text box name `govt=actual-units` and in text box name `result=amount-govt` for above four radio button

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9sHt/1/) of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
div {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
div label {
    width: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
input[readonly] {
    background: #eee;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loads').closest('div').hide();
    $('#units').val('0');
    $('input[name="myradio"]').change(function(){
            if($('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val() == '100')
                $('#loads').closest('div').hide();
            else
                $('#loads').closest('div').show();
    });

    $('input[readonly]').each(function(){
                    $(this).val('0'); 
        });

        $('#actual').val('2.56');
        $("input:radio[name=myradio], #btn-calculate").click(function() {
            if ($('input[name=myradio]:radio:checked').val() == '100'){
               $('#actual').val('2.56');
               $('#charges').val('20');
            } else if ($('input[name=myradio]:radio:checked').val() == '200'){
               $('#actual').val('3.50');
               $('#charges').val('40');
            } else if ($('input[name=myradio]:radio:checked').val() == '300'){
               $('#actual').val('4.50');
               $('#charges').val('60');
            } else if ($('input[name=myradio]:radio:checked').val() == '400'){
               $('#actual').val('5.50');
               $('#charges').val('80');
            }
            $('#tax').val(($('#units').val())*($('#actual').val()));
            $('#elec').val(($('#units').val())*($('#actual').val()));
            $('#amount').val(parseInt(($('#charges').val()))+parseInt(($('#actual').val())));
            $('#govt').val(($('#actual').val())-($('#units').val()));
            $('#result').val(($('#amount').val())-($('#govt').val()));
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="form1">
<label>Select your category:</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="100" name="myradio" checked="checked" />Domestic</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="200" name="myradio" />a</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="300" name="myradio" />b</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="400" name="myradio" />c</label>
    <div>
        <label for="units">No of units(kwh) used</label>
        <input type="text" name="units" id="units" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="loads">Connected loads(kwh)</label>
        <input type="text" name="loads" id="loads" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="actual">Actual</label>
        <input type="text" data-value="2.60" readonly="readonly" name="actual" id="actual" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="tax">Tax</label>
        <input type="text" data-value="0.00" readonly="readonly" name="tax" id="tax" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="charges">Charges</label>
        <input type="text" data-value="20.00" readonly="readonly" name="charges" id="charges" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        <input type="text" data-value="2.60" readonly="readonly" name="amount" id="amount" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="govt">Govt</label>
        <input type="text" data-value="2.60" readonly="readonly" name="govt" id="govt" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="result">Result</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="result" id="result" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="btn-calculate">Calculate</button>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sir my actual value for domestic is 2.56 n charges is 20,for a is 3.50 n charges is 40 ,b is 4.5 n chargers is 60

Comment: these are all default value

Comment: @user2581292 edited the answer. You can use if-else and set the actual values and all other values as needed. Edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9sHt/35/) too.

Comment: i edited my question i paste the code which u give me in my question

Comment: can u plz tell me about my question

Comment: Add a new question and explain your problem properly. I cannot add or edit code in this answer. I could not understand your problem, please explain it properly and put your relevant code in the new question. Put a link to that here. I will try to help.:)

Answer (score 0):

simply use click events for each of the radio buttons;

```
<input type="radio" value="200" name="myradio" id="radio_A"/>a

$('#radio_A').on('click', function() { $('#actual').val(somevalue); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c9sHt/32/

Comment: can u place it in my code n create js fiddle so i will see how its wor5king

Comment: and i also want this Similarly I want this in text box name amount=charges+actual and in text box name govt=actual-units and in text box name result=amount-govt for above four radio button n how can i do this

Comment: i also need to multiply this actual value with the input value that user enter

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691635/how-to-pass-different-values-on-selecting-different-radio-button-in-text-box